# Can I make a dictionary available to multiple python scripts?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of addresses with their usernames and passwords listed that looks something like this:

```
address_dict = {'address1':{'username':'abc', 'password':'123'}, 'address2':{'username':'xyz', 'password':'456'}}
```

Is there a way to make this dictionary accessible for multiple scripts to read from and possibly write to? Like save it as seperate python file and import it or something?

Comment: If I understand you correcctly, then yes, you can just save it in a module and include that module in others.

Comment: don't forget `cPickle`, just a faster version, not always available so use a try and except clause to try import `cPickle` as pickle or if it can't be found use just import `Pickle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do just that:

```
# module.py

address_dict = {'address1':{'username':'abc', 'password':'123'}, 'address2':{'username':'xyz', 'password':'456'}}

# main.py

import module
print(module.address_dict)
```

If you don't like the `module.` prefix, you could import the dictionary like so:

```
from module import address_dict
print(address_dict)
```

Comment: out of the two this is the better option fro passing between files, or else using parameters to give the data to a class or method. Although use `pickle` if you want to save the data to be used after has finished otherwise the data is lost.

Answer (score 3):

To access it and modify it at runtime, you can just define it in a module and then import it. But if you want your changes to be persistent (i.e. see the changed version next time you run the script) you need something else, like a database.

The simplest to use in this case would probably be the [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module, which is based on `pickle`. You can also use `pickle` itself if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at pickle :)

http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

You can use it to dump objects to files and also to read them back in with any other python script.

Comment: Note that `pickle` is for data persistence and is generally used to save data after a program has run so it can be accessed when it is launched again

Comment: Sounds like what OP want's allthough he didn't really specify so I may have missunderstood. After I read write to a file my mind went straight to pickle :)

Comment: he said write to a dict not a file and that he would keep the data in one separate python file, your option is a good one any may well be what the OP wants but its hard to tell

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND thats what I said